# Does SharedPreferences name need to be unique?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Probably a dumb question, but I"m using a SharedPreference with a few different names "MyPrefs1", "MyPrefs2" etc.

I'm assuming this is restricted to my app. i.e. if some other app tries to use the same name, it won't overwrite my values

I pretty much believe my understanding is correct, but the name "SharedPreferences" seem to indicate that it can be shared between apps? (is it for Sharing between activities?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's correct, the SharedPreferences are stored in your app's private folder (to be exact, in /data/data/your package name/shared_prefs).

You can give them whatever name you want.

Comment: That’s true only if you get your shared preferences with PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().

Comment: @mvai please elaborate If i use getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_JSON, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); with my own name, it's not private?

Comment: @zooter yes, it’s private because you used Context.MODE_PRIVATE .

Answer (score 3):

`SharedPreferences` represent the preferences which can be shared between different components of your application. The `SharedPreferences` you create in your application is never exposed with other applications.
Whether you use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` or  `Context.getSharedPreferences("file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` both are particular to your application only.

Note - `SharedPreferences` or `Preferences`  is not exposed to other applications.

Answer (score 3):

Although you assumption is right that the SharedPreferences are not shared between apps and thus names cannot clash, it's a good practice (besides of put a specific name to your shared preferences file) to add the package of your application as a prefix. This is useful if you have different flavours and you don't want to overwrite your preferences among them, especially when you're testing an app and don't want to screw up the original values of the shared preferences files.

Comment: this is a combination of a thank you note, personal opinion and an attempt to comment. If you implement constrcutive feedback that is missing from both other answers your answer becomes more valid than currently is. Please update and or repost as comment (once enough rep.) (From Review).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23477502)

Comment: @ZF007 disagree, although it needs improvement, I don't think its a comment, it could be a valid answer.

Comment: @batero is that edit okay (I tried to focus more on the question, but I'm not an android expert so ...) ?

Comment: @JonasWilms that's right. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough in my answer